# Append DataGrid inside of DataGrids RowDetailsTemplate

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

this appears to bind, but rows in Details Grid are empty. Something is off/missing?

I've also tried {Binding SubCustomers}

SubCustomers is a List on parent object.

I am able to bind this way to single Fields such as FirstName etc.. just not the subcollection..

```
        <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source=SubCustomers}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to bind to a property on the `DataContext` of the parent, not on that particular row.  So, the `DataContext` of the `RowDetails` is the row item, and in order to get the parent's property, you need to use `RelativeSource` bindings.  If you bind to the `DataContext` of the parent, you can then "dot-down" to the property you actually care about:

```
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.SubCustomers, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
```

Comment: thanks. 
That still does not work, and now instead of getting a grid in details with empty rows, i just get empty space. 

also,
if DataContext of the parent is not of particular row, why does this work correctly? 

<TextBlock Text="{Binding FirstName}" />

Comment: The details is the row... I thought your SubCustomers was on the parent list (that doesn't make much sense, I know, but that is how I read your question). In that case, you should be able to bind directly to the list.  Is the list populated at all times?  If not, is it an ObservableCollection?